# Is this C code accessing out of bounds pointer?

Tags: c

I'm not too familiar with C, and I'm trying to debug a seg fault.

We have a piece of code in a loop that is doing

```
// index is computed previously based on loop parameters

buffer[index] = .....
```

I added `printf("size of array %lu, index is %zu \n", sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), index);`

and it printed the size of the array as `1` but index is greater than `1`. This tells me its out of bounds, but because I'm not too familiar with C, I'm wondering if there's a catch to my method of analysis? This piece of software should be relatively bug proof so I'm a bit surprised something like this hasn't been caught before.

I had to trace up the chain to find how `buffer` is defined. I see that it's defined as

```
const size_t buffer_size = sizeof(void*) *
      ((mr - 1) + batch_size * op->oh * op->sh);
const void** buffer = (const void**)realloc(op->buffer, buffer_size)
```

I need to trace where all these parameters on the RHS came from

Comment: Note: `sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0])` is a `size_t`.  Use `"%zu"`.

Comment: C does not require index checking to see if the index is in bounds.

Comment: How is `buffer` declared?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ah okay, I switched it to `%zu` and stil have the same results (unsurprisingly). and yes, I understand it does not do automatic bounds checking. I was just saying I'm surprised this piece of code has a bug that no one's noticed until now

Comment: Is `buffer` an array or a pointer?

Comment: Is `buffer` a function argument?

Comment: Run the code through valgrind.  If it's mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: @Gerhardh Just edited the OP. It looks like buffer is a 2D array?

Comment: `buffer` is a pointer, so `sizeof(buffer)` will give you size of a pointer (probably 8, but depends on your architecture), not the size of the memory block it points to.

Comment: From the edit, `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of the pointer. You *know* the size, because you reallocated it. It's `buffer_size`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, technically. The function reads in a pointer called `op` and the buffer is obtained using `buffer = op->buffer`

Comment: You clearly defined a pointer: `const void** buffer`.

Comment: Arrays have `[]` in the definition. You have pointers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre].

Comment: The relationship must be: `index < (buffer_size / sizeof(void *))`. So, where does `index` get set?

Comment: Just did a valgrind and I'm seeing `==1839378==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x130A7000`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this C code accessing out of bounds pointer?

Not determinable from posted code.

> I added `printf("size of array %lu, index is %zu \n", sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), index);` and it printed the size of the array as 1 but index is greater than 1.

"it printed the size of the array as 1" is unfounded as `buffer` is a *pointer* and not an *array*.  `sizeof(buffer)` is the size of a pointer and not the size of the allocation from `realloc(op->buffer, buffer_size)`.

To see the size of the allocation, use

```
printf("allocation element count %zu, index is %zu\n",
   buffer_size / sizeof buffer[0], index);`
```

---

Suggested re-write for better clarity: Drop unneeded casts, make sure size calculation done to at least `size_t` math, form `buffer_n` to save the allocation element count.

```
// const size_t buffer_size = sizeof(void*) *
//     ((mr - 1) + batch_size * op->oh * op->sh);
// const void** buffer = (const void**)realloc(op->buffer, buffer_size)

// Additional code needed to handle cases where this assert is not true.
assert(mr > 0 && batch_size > 0 && op->oh > 0 && op->sh > 0);
const size_t buffer_n = (mr - 1) + (size_t)1 * batch_size * op->oh * op->sh;
const void** buffer = realloc(op->buffer, sizeof buffer[0] * buffer_n);

printf("allocation count %zu, index is %zu\n", buffer_n, index);`
```

Even better code would look for overflow in `(mr - 1) + (size_t)1 * batch_size * op->oh * op->sh`.